# populate UITableView from json

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to populate a `UITableView` with data from json result. I can get it to load from `plist` array no problem and I can even see my json. The problem I'm having is that the `UITableView` never gets to see the json results. please bear with me as this is my first time with Objective-C.

In my .h file

```
@interface TableViewViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSArray *exercises;
    NSMutableData *responseData;

}
```

In my .m file

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return  exercises.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //create a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
    reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    // fill it with contnets
    cell.textLabel.text = [exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // return it
    return cell;
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {       
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_to_json"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self ];


    // load from plist
    //NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"exercise" ofType:@"plist"];
    //exercises = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSArray *response = [dictionary objectForKey:@"response"];

    exercises = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response];
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to tell your table view to reload. Try adding:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

at the end of your -connectionDidFinishLoading method.

Comment: Okay. Is your view controller a UITableViewController or just a UIViewController? You will need an outlet to your UITableView. If your view controller is a UITableViewController, change the above code to [[self tableView] reloadData]; Otherwise, declare a UITableView IBOutlet in your header file and name it tableView and connect it in Interface Builder. Then the code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the following line of code at the end of your connectionDidFinishLoading method:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This will refresh the UITableView on the main thread since connectionDidFinishLoading is being performed on a different thread.